# How can I valid email and print data from form to another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I want to check the validity of the email, but if I don't enter any characters in the input, it works fine. But if I enter some characters, it doesn't work. What can be problem ?

Another problem is that after submitting the form I want to open a new html sub-file and in it I want to print the data I have written to the form in the original html file. Something like *A confirmation email has been sent to xyz@xyz.com*. How can I achieve this ?

HTML

```
        <form method="get" class="form" action="./subscript.html" target="_self">
          <small>Email address</small>
          <small class="valid-notice">Valid email required</small>

          <input class="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@company.com"/>
          <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe to monthly newsletter"/>
        </form>
```

JS

```
let emailInput = document.querySelector(".email"),
  form = document.querySelector(".form");
  
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!test(emailInput.value)) {
    errorEmail(emailInput);
  } else {
    e.currentTarget.submit();
  }
});

function test(email) {
  let validEmail = /^[^\.\s][\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,}$/gm;
  return validEmail.test(email);
}

function errorEmail(input) {
  let valid = document.querySelector(".valid-notice");
  input.classList.add("error-border");
  valid.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Comment: `return email.length && validEmail.test(email);`

Comment: still doesnt work properly

Comment: so if you leave it blank it passes validation? what about `return email.trim().length && validEmail.test(email);`

Comment: you realise that `e.currentTarget.submit();` will just try to submit the form again, which will call your code again, which will submit the form again ... you get the idea

Comment: When I leave the input empty, it works correctly = it turns red and gives an error.

If I enter the correct email format, e.g. xyz@gmail.com, it works correctly and the form is submitted

The problem is if I enter an incorrect format e.g. "ash#company.com". I expect the field to turn red and throw an error, but it doesn't happen

Comment: Ahhh, because `submit` isn't even triggered with an invalid input

Comment: thanks, so how can I edit my code ?

Comment: don't use `type="email"` if you're going to validate it yourself

Comment: thank you! It finally work. Could you help me with my second question ?

Comment: Nope, I don't do server side stuff

Answer (score -1):

#### For the second question :

```js
let emailInput = document.querySelector(".email"),
  form = document.querySelector(".form");
  
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!test(emailInput.value)) {
    errorEmail(emailInput);
  } else {
    emailInput.classList.remove("error-border");
    var message = document.createElement("p");
    message.textContent = "A confirmation email has been sent to " + emailInput.value + ".";
    document.body.replaceChildren(message);
  }
});

function test(email) {
  let validEmail = /^[^\.\s][\w\-]+(\.[\w\-]+)*@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,}$/gm;
  return validEmail.test(email);
}

function errorEmail(input) {
  let valid = document.querySelector(".valid-notice");
  input.classList.add("error-border");
  valid.style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

```css
.error-border {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form method="get" class="form" action="./subscript.html" target="_self">
  <small>Email address</small>
  <small class="valid-notice">Valid email required</small>
  
  <input class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email@company.com">
  <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Subscribe to monthly newsletter">
</form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).